# How to use AFrame Inspector tool with 8th wall

Tags: aframe, 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

I'm currently using 8th Wall paid plan to develop some scenes for mobile web AR.

In their docs, they mention running the A-Frame Inspector tool: [8th Wall Docs- Visual Inspector and Dev Tools](https://github.com/8thwall/8frame/blob/master/docs/introduction/visual-inspector-and-dev-tools.md).

They don't mention how to actually run the A-Frame Inspector tool with 8th Wall.

Can anyone help and explain to me how to run an 8th Wall project on my computer locally so I can run the A-Frame Inspector tool to help build my scenes?

I'm not trying to host this locally, but instead be able to visit the scene in my computer's browser without having to run it on a mobile device.

It seems like everything I try, I have to scan the QR Code and run it on my mobile device and use the A-Frame Inspector tool on my phone.  I'd like the ability to use the A-Frame Inspector tool through my laptop's browser.

Answer (score 0):

You view the A-Frame scene in your computer's browser using metaversal deployment (`<a-scene ... xrweb="allowedDevices: any">`).

Once you have the scene open on your computer, open the A-Frame inspector by pressing `<ctrl> + <alt> + i` on PC or `<ctrl> + <option> + i` on Mac. See the [aframe-inspector documentation](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-inspector) for more information.

Comment: those are instructions to open the inspector only! the problem is that when you use the inspector of AFRAME when using 8thWall, changing any values in the screen (position, scale, components, etc) doesn't work, It simply just does nothing. Ideally this would work exactly like the standalone AFRAME inspector does

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the play button in the upper left corner to use the pan/rotate/zoom shortcuts provided by A-Frame Inspector.